# How can I make the wit.ai bot to skip some responses

Tags: wit.ai

How can I make the wit.ai bot to skip some user responses?
e.g. say user said " I am doing fine" on that Bot should not respond, or wait for next user input.

Answer (score 0):

Check the response before sending it on to Wit. An if/else statement should be enough.